# .load is doing a post instead of get

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

$('#div1').load(url, { 
        id1=ident1, 
        id2=ident2 
    }, function() { 
        // Foo
    })

is doing a post instead of what I thought should be a get. Is there a way to make it a get?

Thanks,
rod.

Comment: Giving you the benefit of a doubt, you've gotta read the documentation before you ask.

Comment: Whatever happened to "There is no such thing as a dumb question?" Your answer was a big help to me, so I'll go and read the documentation. What are these forums for "Intelligent people who need intelligent help" Kind of an oxymoron if you ask me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) "**The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.**"

Use [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param) to serialize the data first.

```
$('#div1').load(url, jQuery.param({ 
    id1:ident1, 
    id2:ident2 
}), function() { 
    // Foo
})
```

Just noticed your example is syntactically invalid as well. Object literals use ":", not "=", to relate a object key to its value.